# How to write 0.9 to the power of 3 (with variables) in Swift

Tags: swift

I´m working on a math program in Xcode Command Line Tool and have some troubles writing the maths in coding.

I want the program to to take to variables (p and x) and find the power of them (p^x).

This is my code now:

```
import Foundation

var x = 3
var p = 0.9

let squared = pow(p, x)

print(squared)
```

I get the error: No exact matches in call to global function 'pow'

Can someone help me solve this ? :D

Comment: This isn't SwiftUI. This is Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into the issue because the compiler is doing automatic type inference and `x` and `p` are inferred to be different types.

Here's what the compiler infers the types to be:

```
var x: Int = 3
var p: Double = 0.9
```

That's a problem, because there's no `pow` function that takes a combination of `Int` and `Double`.

Here's what you probably want:

```
var x: Double = 3
var p: Double = 0.9

let squared = pow(p, x)

print(squared)
```

Or, alternately, the compiler can infer `x` as a `Double` if you include the decimal:

```
var x = 3.0
var p = 0.9
```

In both of the above cases, the compiler uses the `pow` function that takes `Double`s for both arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is that Generic function `pow()` has no match with two different data type

x -> Int, p -> Double

You can set
`var x = 3.0`

Basically type for x and p should be same.

Comment: Not merely just the same. `pow` only exists for `Float` and `Double`

Comment: And `pow` is not a generic function.

Comment: Actually there is definition for `(_ x: Decimal, _ y: Int) -> Decimal` as well. By Generic i meant overloaded methods. Sorry for wrong choice of words.